# how to configure grunt copy task

Tags: file, gruntjs, copy

I have a directory:

```html
- app/
    - monday/
          a.js
          b.js
    - tuesday/
          a.js
          b.js
```

And I configured as below in Grunt：

```html
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
    src: ['**/*.js'],
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/',
    ext: '.js'
}]
```

Then Grunt will create a directory:

```html
- build/
    - monday/
          a.js
          b.js
    - tuesday/
          a.js
          b.js
```

But how can I get the created directory structure like this:

```html
- build/
    - monday/
        - wrap/
              a.js
              b.js
    - tuesday/
        - wrap/
              a.js
              b.js
```

I've tried

```html
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
    src: ['**/*.js'],
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/wrap',
    ext: '.js'
}]
```

and ... But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the current configuration as you want to interpose folders in a structured hierachy retrieved by "**".

**But**:

One always forgets that Grunt file is not only declarative as it may appear when you look at it but it is *plain Javascript* so you can write a function to grab the *src* (like `src: [getMySourceFiles()]`) and you can write another function to return the *dest* value: `dest: placeThemHere()`. 
Moreover, you can write a function that will return the entire config object for *copy* or even more sections.

This way you have the power to play with it in a way that is as complex as you can handle.

Hope this helps anyone remember that grunt is actually javascript, not json.